# Not able to use .net Remoting

Tags: .net

i can't find using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp; as well

what is wrong here is my platform do not support it

i am using VS 2010 professional on windows XP SP3

`C:\VISUAL_STUDIO_2010\C#\Remoting_Server\Remoting_Server\Program.cs(13,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TcpServerChannel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Remoting is old technology and has been superseded - you should look at using WCF for new applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure you have a reference in your project to `System.Runtime.Remoting`. Ensure your using contains:

```
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp;
```

Comment: yes i added reference to `System.Runtime.Remoting ` and it works thanks

Answer (score 1):

just add the reference `System.Runtime.Remoting` in your project 
and then you can use the namespace

```
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp;
```

without any error